# Does CIL expose the CD capabilities?

Tags: web8

In my web application running with SDL Web 8.1.1 I want to know wheter XPM is enabled for the Content Delivery environment. Do the Content Interaction Libraries expose a method to query if the Content Delivery environment has XPM capabilities?

I checked the [SDL Web 8 Content Delivery API (Java)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF) documentation in but that does not seem to document anything related.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's possible to query the service for this. Unfortunately, as you say, the documentation is sketchy, so there's an amount of reverse-engineering to do.

Assuming that [you have already obtained a token](https://blog.indivirtual.nl/testing-sdl-web-8-micro-services/), you can check on the PreviewWebService capability like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=$Authorization} `
    -Uri http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/Environment/PreviewWebServiceCapability
```

(Of course, that's Powershell - YMMV in Java)

If you want to have more of a dig around, it's interesting to start with querying `http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc/$metadata`

Comment: @peter-kjaer is currently working on a PowerShell module with support for automatically querying the capabilities of a given environment.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I guess the answer is that CIL does not support this, but we can query the CD discovery service directly.

Comment: The fact that I do not know of CIL support for this is not evidence that it does not exist.

Comment: That's why I said "I guess". I am not sure either. ;)